# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\wamp\www\form1.php on line 2

Tags: php

```
<form action="form1.php"  method="POST">
    username <input type="text" name="username"><br />
    password <input type="password" name="password"><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submitbutt" value="Login!"><br />
</form>
```

when to add the  lines on the code,the procedure runs error ：

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\wamp\www\form1.php on line 2

```
<?php
<form action="form1.php"  method="POST">
    username <input type="text" name="username"><br />
    password <input type="password" name="password"><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submitbutt" value="Login!"><br />
</form>
?>
```

Comment: why `<?php`  & `?>` for html code o_O

Comment: There is 0 php anywhere in the above post.   Why is it using PHP tags at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

echo the html code...

```
<?php
echo '<form action="form1.php"  method="POST">
    username <input type="text" name="username"><br />
    password <input type="password" name="password"><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submitbutt" value="Login!"><br />
</form>';
?>
```

Or use only html

```
<?php #your php code ?>
<form action="form1.php"  method="POST">
    username <input type="text" name="username"><br />
    password <input type="password" name="password"><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submitbutt" value="Login!"><br />
</form>
<?php #your php code ?>
```

Comment: Or just don't involve PHP at all for something that's only HTML...

Answer (score 2):

You're putting HTML in a PHP block, so your web server is trying to parse the HTML as PHP - and fails, so you get an error back.

All you have to do is *not* enclose it in `<?php ... ?>`, and the HTML will show nicely. You only have to use `<?php ... ?>` when you have actual PHP code to place within it.